# javascript: разбить строку с использованием любого "пробельного" разделителя

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, split, separator

подскажите как поэллегантнее разбить разбить строку, используя в качестве разделителя пробел, табуляцию или иной "пробельный" разделитель

использовать регулярки?

Comment: регулярки, по `\s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str.split(/\s/gi).filter((s) => s.length)
```

Comment: что-то не проходит :(

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: все, отбой - разобрался - указал регулярку как строку, а не как регулярку :)

Comment: @Zhihar, бывает)

Answer (score 1):

Как уже подсказали верно, любой пробельный символ в регулярных выражениях это `\s`

```js
const str = `1  2 3
4    5`;
const reg = /\s+/
console.log(str.split(reg));
```

В данном случае `\s` подставлен квантификатор `+` означающий один и более пробельный символ.

Пример без использования квантификатора:

```js
const str = `1  2   3
4    5`;
const reg = /\s/
console.log(str.split(reg));
```

Как видно, что за разделитель берется только один пробельный символ